# Windowed Average, accounting for gaps

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, analytic-functions, rolling-average

I need to calculate an average over the preceding 4 weeks...

```
SELECT
  *,
  AVG(val) OVER (PARTITION BY some_identifier, day_of_week_column
                     ORDER BY date_column
                  ROW BETWEEN 4 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
                )
                   AS preceding_4_week_average
FROM
  myTable
```

The data, however, is "sparse"

In this case my window function should look back "4 weeks" rather than "4 rows".
- A missing date is not a `0` it's implicitly a `NULL`

```
 thing | date       | dow | val | avg
   1   | 2018-01-01 |  1  |  1  | NULL  <= AVG({})
   1   | 2018-01-08 |  1  |  2  | 1     <= AVG({1})
   1   | 2018-01-15 |  1  |  3  | 1.5   <= AVG({1,2})
   1   | 2018-01-22 |  1  |  4  | 2     <= AVG({1,2,3})
   1   | 2018-01-29 |  1  |  5  | 2.5   <= AVG({1,2,3,4})

   1   | 2018-02-12 |  1  |  7  | 4     <= AVG({3,4,5})
   1   | 2018-02-19 |  1  |  8  | 5.33  <= AVG({4,5,7})
   1   | 2018-02-26 |  1  |  9  | 6.66  <= AVG({5,7,8})
   1   | 2018-03-05 |  1  |  10 | 8     <= AVG({7,8,9})
   1   | 2018-03-12 |  1  |  11 | 11.25 <= AVG({7,8,9,10})
   1   | 2018-03-19 |  1  |  12 | 9.5   <= AVG({8,9,10,11})
```

Note : There is no value for 2018-02-05

I would normally approach it in one of two ways...

1. LEFT JOIN on to a template to "force" all the dates to exist, and rely on `AVG()` effectively "ignoring" NULLs.

This is less than ideal as the number of "things" is huge and constructing this template is expensive.

```
SELECT
  *,
  AVG(mytable.val) OVER (PARTITION BY things.id, dates.dow
                             ORDER BY dates.date
                          ROW BETWEEN 4 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
                        )
                           AS preceding_4_week_average
FROM
  things
CROSS JOIN
  dates
LEFT JOIN
  myTable
    ON  myTable.date = dates.date
    AND myTable.id   = things.id
```

2. Don't use window functions, use a self join instead

This is less than ideal as there are hundreds of columns in myTable and BigQuery isn't performing very well on that.

```
SELECT
  myTable.*,
  AVG(hist.val)   AS preceding_4_week_average
FROM
  myTable
LEFT JOIN
  myTable   AS hist
    ON  hist.id    = myTable.id
    AND hist.date >= myTable.date - INTERVAL 28 DAYS
    AND hist.date <  myTable.date
GROUP BY
  myTable.column1,
  myTable.column2,
  etc, etc
```

***The actual question***

Does anyone else have an alternative, preferably using windowed/analytic functions to "look back 4 weeks" rather than "look back 4 rows"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

As you will see  - the trick is in using `RANGE` instead of `ROW`

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *,
  AVG(val) OVER(
    PARTITION BY id, dow 
    ORDER BY DATE_DIFF(DATE_TRUNC(date, WEEK), DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), WEEK), WEEK) 
    RANGE BETWEEN 4 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
  ) AVG
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

You can test, play with above using dummy data from your question as below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, DATE '2018-01-01' date, 1 dow, 1 val UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, '2018-01-08', 1, 2  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, '2018-01-15', 1, 3  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, '2018-01-22', 1, 4  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, '2018-01-29', 1, 5  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, '2018-02-12', 1, 7  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, '2018-02-19', 1, 8  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, '2018-02-26', 1, 9  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, '2018-03-05', 1, 10 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, '2018-03-12', 1, 11 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, '2018-03-19', 1, 12  
)
SELECT *,
  AVG(val) OVER(
    PARTITION BY id, dow 
    ORDER BY DATE_DIFF(DATE_TRUNC(date, WEEK), DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), WEEK), WEEK) 
    RANGE BETWEEN 4 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
  ) avg
FROM `project.dataset.table`
-- ORDER BY date
```

with result as

```
Row id      date    dow val avg 
1   1   2018-01-01  1   1   null     
2   1   2018-01-08  1   2   1.0  
3   1   2018-01-15  1   3   1.5  
4   1   2018-01-22  1   4   2.0  
5   1   2018-01-29  1   5   2.5  
6   1   2018-02-12  1   7   4.0  
7   1   2018-02-19  1   8   5.333333333333333    
8   1   2018-02-26  1   9   6.666666666666667    
9   1   2018-03-05  1   10  8.0  
10  1   2018-03-12  1   11  8.5  
11  1   2018-03-19  1   12  9.5
```

Comment: . . This is an excellent answer.  I've tried the equivalent logic on SQL Server, Postgres, and Oracle and it doesn't work.  BigQuery's interpretation of the `range` clause makes a lot of sense, although I am still surprised that it is able to count the gaps in the dates.

Answer (score 0):

This is brute force, but it should be faster:

```
select t.*,
       ((case when date_1 >= date_add(date, interval -4 week)
              then val_1 else 0
         end) +
        (case when date_2 >= date_add(date, interval -4 week)
              then val_2 else 0
         end) +
        (case when date_3 >= date_add(date, interval -4 week)
              then val_3 else 0
         end) +
        (case when date_4 >= date_add(date, interval -4 week)
              then val_4 else 0
         end)
        ) /
       ((case when date_1 >= date_add(date, interval -4 week)
              then 1 else 0
         end) +
        (case when date_2 >= date_add(date, interval -4 week)
              then 1 else 0
         end) +
        (case when date_3 >= date_add(date, interval -4 week)
              then 1 else 0
         end) +
        (case when date_4 >= date_add(date, interval -4 week)
              then 1 else 0
         end)
        )        
from (select t.*,
             lag(val, 1) over (partition by id, dow order by date) as val_1,
             lag(val, 2) over (partition by id, dow order by date) as val_2,
             lag(val, 3) over (partition by id, dow order by date) as val_3,
             lag(val, 4) over (partition by id, dow order by date) as val_4,
             lag(date, 1) over (partition by id, dow order by date) as date_1,
             lag(date, 2) over (partition by id, dow order by date) as date_2,
             lag(date, 3) over (partition by id, dow order by date) as date_3,
             lag(date, 4) over (partition by id, dow order by date) as date_4
   from mytable t
     ) t;
```

There is probably a clever way to express this using arrays, but it's a bit earlier where I am.

Comment: Did think of that too, but squirmed away from it. Future iterations of the code might want a 52 week average.  I'll have a look around as to what BQ can do with arrays though. Thanks.